# Connect Android App with a Firebird Database

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, firebird

I use Android Studio to program an application which allows you to access a Firebird database

I already read that it is not recommended to connect the app directly with the database. Therefore I would highly appreciate if someone could provide a step-by-step instruction on how to establish a connection between a Firebird database and an android application.

Comment: Step 1. Don't do it. But jokes aside, you really should not connect directly to remote database servers from Android. Build a rest service that talks to your database, let your Android application talk to that rest service. Give your question is far too broad, I have voted to close.

Comment: And how should I build a rest service? I really don‘t have this sort of experience to build some sort of service... Does some sort of explanation exist which I could start reading?

Comment: Or a sample code

Comment: Asking how to build that is too broad for stack overflow, and asking for suggestions for tutorials or books (which exist, lots of both tutorials and books) is explicitly off topic.

Comment: I know, that's why I am asking for a suggestion or recommendation on what to read

Comment: ...which is equally opinions based and akin to holy wars. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+rest  Quote: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: and if i don't have acces to the back-end?